# Working with Sockets in Python - f-strings: Invalid syntax

Tags: python, sockets, formatting

I'm learning about connecting to sockets, sending and receiving bytes.

I'm following a book and a tutorial. In the tutorial the gentelman formats a string to include the length of a message as well as a buffer for the header of the message + the message itself. My formatted string seems to be the same as in the video, yet it comes back with an invalid syntax pointing to `"`.

```
msg = f"{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}" + msg
```

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax      ^`

I checked syntax for f-strings and this is what it says:

```
>>> name = "Eric"
>>> age = 74
>>> f"Hello, {name}. You are {age}."
```

I am using python 3.7 as in the video. - https://youtu.be/8A4dqoGL62E?t=326

```
import socket

HEADERSIZE = 10

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 1240))
s.listen(5)

while True:
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print(address)

    msg = "Welcome to the server!"
    msg = f"{len(msg):<{HEADERSIZE}}" + msg

    clientsocket.send(bytes("Welcome to the server!"))
```

Comment: @Amadan Sorry, could you tell me what it means that I can't interpolate the format specifier? I don't know what to do with that information. Thank you!

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong and deleted the comment.

Comment: Are you sure you're using 3.7? Comment out the `msg = f"..."` line, and add `import sys; print(sys.version_info)` at the top. If you don't get `major=3, minor=7`, shenanigans. I get your error in older Pythons, but your code compiles okay in 3.7.

Comment: @Amadan I just left my station, I will make sure when I come back and I will comment letting you know

Comment: @Amadan Indeed it's showing that I'm using version 2.7 for some reason. I just checked and there are multiple versions installed on the machine. I set 3.7 to be the default and it works. Thank you